# Excel VBA delete specific columns in one row

Tags: excel, vba

I am searching for a name in one row in excel. I would like to delete all columns before that name till a specific column
E.g. my Name is in column 10 and I want to delete all from column 2 to column 9 so that column 10 with my name will be then at position of column 2.

```
Sub delete_cells()
Dim rg As Range
 Set rg = ActiveSheet.Rows(2).Find(What:="Name", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)
 If Not rg Is Nothing Then
    If rg.Column > 1 Then ActiveSheet.Columns("4:" & rg.Column - 3).Delete
 Else
     MsgBox "Something
 End If
End Sub
```

I get an run time error. Why?

EDIT explanation:

[image: Image of what I have and What i need]

I need to search for "Name" in row 2 and take all values from Column I, J, K etc. to Column E. So I need columns E to H to be deleted and move columns I, J etc. only for the given row. There should no columns of other rows being deleted.

Comment: rg.column is 355 what it should be. I get an error during executing the code``Then ActiveSheet.Columns("4:" & rg.Column - 3).Delete``. It gives an application or object defined error.

Comment: That was just an example. I need to delete the columns 4 to rg.Column - 3. So all Columns between 4 and 355 (included 4 and 355).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Delete Columns Before

- While developing code for deleting rows or columns, it is a good idea to use `Select` instead of `Delete`, and only when the code is finished, switch to `Delete`.
- `Resize` and `Offset` will accurately define the search range.
- The `LookIn` parameter `xlFormulas` will allow finding an occurrence in a hidden column.
- The parameter of the `After` argument, `.Cells(.Cells.Count)` (defining the last cell) will make the search start from the first cell of the range.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteColumns()
    
    Const cRow As Long = 2
    Const cCol As Long = 2
    Const Criteria As String = "Name"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim fCell As Range
    With ws.Rows(cRow)
        Set fCell = .Resize(, .Columns.Count - cCol).Offset(, cCol) _
            .Find(Criteria, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    End With
    If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
        ws.Columns(cCol).Resize(, fCell.Column - cCol).Select ' .Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not find '" & Criteria & "'.", vbExclamation, "Not Found"
    End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

```
Sub deleteColumns()
    
    Const cRow As Long = 2
    Const cCol As Long = 4
    Const Criteria As String = "Name"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim fCell As Range
    With ws.Rows(cRow)
        Set fCell = .Resize(, .Columns.Count - cCol).Offset(, cCol) _
            .Find(Criteria, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
        If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
            .Columns(cCol).Resize(, fCell.Column - cCol).Delete xlToLeft
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not find '" & Criteria & "'.", _
            vbExclamation, "Not Found"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

You could put cRow in the arguments section:

```
Sub deleteColumns(ByVal cRow As Long)
```

and delete the line `Const cRow As Long = 2`.
Then you could use `deleteColumns(i)` in the loop of another procedure.

Comment: When I was executing the macro, nothing happens. It did not delete anything

Comment: To make it work for your data mentioned in your comments, you will have to set `cCol` to `4` and replace `Select` with `Delete`.

Comment: Yes sorry. I did not read it. One problem is that i just need the first row values to be deleted. Is it possible to adapt the code only for the colums of the first row so that i can use a for-loop for each row to search after my Name and only delete columns of that specific row?

Comment: I added a new version. This time it will delete.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you mean by ``deleteColumns(i)`` in the loop of another procedure. But your edited code still changes all rows and not only row 2

Comment: It's still working on my end. It only 'touches' row 2 (`cRow`).

Comment: After seeing the image, you will have to use 5 as `cCol`. You should copy/paste the second code to make sure you got the right one.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of `columns` can be

- column letter(s), representing a Column: `Columns("B")`
- a number, representing the column number:  `Columns(2)`
- two column letter(s), separated with a colon, representing from and to columns `Columns("B:AA")`

However, it is not possible to pass two numbers separated with colon: `Columns("2:4")` is invalid.

I think the easiest way for you is to use the `resize`-method:

```
Sub delete_cells(findName As String)
    const firstColToDelete = 2    ' (you have 4 in your code, change as you need)

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ActiveSheet.Rows(2).Find(what:=findName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)
 
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        Dim colsToDelete As Range
        Set colsToDelete = ActiveSheet.Columns(firstColToDelete).Resize(, rg.Column - firstColToDelete)
        colsToDelete.Delete
    Else
         MsgBox "Something"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Update:** To just delete the columns from your header row (row 2), change the code to

```
    Dim colsToDelete As Range
    Set colsToDelete = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, firstColToDelete).Resize(, rg.Column - firstColToDelete)

    colsToDelete.Delete xlShiftToLeft
```

Note that this will leave your rightmost data columns without header. Is this what you intent?

Comment: @SJR: Yes, you could. But it would result in *rows* 2:4, not *columns*

Comment: That worked but was not quite what i was expecting. What I need to do is to not only delete columns, but also put my name to the front and only for first row and not for other rows.

Comment: @Checka Not sure if I understand. Could you add a picture showing what you want to your question?